Print invoice for thermal printer, string formatting issue in javaFX application
I am facing a string formatting issue during printing an invoice. The invoice is not properly aligned as I required.
The code simply generate a invoice bill to the thermal printer. If printer device not found, it will get default printing media of the system.
My code is below.
public static String padRight(String s, int n) {
    return String.format("%-" + n + "s", s);
}

public static String padRightInt(int s, int n) {
    return String.format("%-" + n + "d", s);
}

public static void printIvoice(Node node){
    Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
    PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(printer);
    double scale = 0.791;
    node.getTransforms().add(new Scale(scale, scale));
    boolean success = printerJob.printPage(node);
    if (success) {
        printerJob.endJob();
    }
}

public static Node getPrintableText(String[] products){
    Label text = new Label();
    text.setFont(Font.font("Monospaced Regular", FontWeight.LIGHT, 11));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("             Company Name            \n");
    stringBuilder.append("---------------------------------------------" + "\n");
    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%-40s %5s %10s\n", "Item", "Qty", "Price"));
    stringBuilder.append(String.format( "%-40s %5s %10s\n", "----", "---", "-----"));
    for(String product: products){

        if(product.trim().length() > 25){
            String firstLine = product.trim().substring(0, 25);
            stringBuilder.append(firstLine).append(" ").append("\n");
            String lastLine = product.trim().substring(25);
            int spaces = 50 - lastLine.length();
            stringBuilder.append( String.format(padRight(lastLine, spaces), lastLine) + String.format(padRightInt(1, 10), 1) +" "+ String.format(padRightInt(1000, 10), 1000)).append("\n");
        }else{
            String temp = product.trim();
            int spaces = 50 - temp.length();
            stringBuilder.append( String.format(padRight(temp, spaces), temp) + String.format(padRightInt(1, 10), 1) +" "+ String.format(padRightInt(1000, 10), 1000)).append("\n");
        }
    }
    stringBuilder.append("_____________________________________________" + "\n");
    stringBuilder.append("Net Amount                                 5000"  + "\n");
    stringBuilder.append("_____________________________________________" + "\n");
    stringBuilder.append("Thank you so much!" + "\n");
    text.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
    return text;
}

Here is the main method to call this code.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] productName = {
            "Android",
            "Mac OS",
            "Windows 10 Operating System",
            "Linux Operating System",
            "Windows Server OS"
    };
    Node node = getPrintableText(productName);
    printIvoice(node);
}

The code output is below

I want to align the output according to product name length.
I tried to format it through extra spaces, but it's not working. I want to align the quantity and price columns properly. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Sanity check: Is the output properly formatted when you print it to the console? If not, then note this problem is not directly related to JavaFX, in which case removing all references to JavaFX would make the question more focused (it would also be easier to provide a proper [mre] in this case).

Fonts are divided into fixed-width fonts and unequal-width fonts. If you want to use it for billing, please make sure you use a fixed-width font. This way you can use how many character widths you can use for arrangement and alignment.

Yes, that's not a monospaced font, so won't conform to your calculations

I used text.setFont(Font.font("Monospaced Regular", FontWeight.LIGHT, 11)); to the Label. It not worked. Font Console tried as well.

Where in the code is the mono space font setting?

In the getPrintableText() function, second line.
text.setFont(Font.font("Monospaced Regular", FontWeight.LIGHT, 11));

I don't see how that code is going to be of any real-world use. You are currently hard-coding most of the output. It would surely all need to be parameterized in order to be of actual use

The code simply generate a invoice bill to the thermal printer. If printer device not found, it will get default printing media of the system.

google keyword: "java 热敏小票打印机" or https://github.com/hncdyj123/ticket-print , result image: https://github.com/hncdyj123/ticket-print/blob/master/image/IMG_0711.JPG

@life888888 This example based on awt and my application is based on JavaFX.

Of course if you treat your 'sale' properly and ensure it's saved in a MySql db, issuing a query like mysql -p  testdb -e 'select substring(Product, 1, 25) as Product, Quantity as Qty, Price  from Sale' will get you a perfectly formed table

Bro, its not about the database communication. Its about to format and print the data.

You mean like THIS? (that comes from a database)

I’m pretty sure "Monospaced Regular" is not a valid family.  Valid font families are listed here.  Try just "monospace" instead (notice it has no d in it).

@VGR Actually Java lists it for me as Monospaced on my system

@g00se Interestingly, both Monospace and Monospaced work for me, by which I mean they produce a monospaced font.  But "Monospaced Regular" does not, which is not surprising, since it’s not the name of a family.

Note the Font::font static methods take a font family, whereas the constructor takes a font name. Using either Font.font("Monospaced") or new Font("Monospaced Regular", size) should work.

Or CSS: -fx-font-family: "Monospaced"; / -fx-font: normal <size> "Monospaced";.

@g00se yes, exactly

@VGR the font-family is working with d and without d. but problem not solved.

If you are able to print with a monospaced font, which should allow characters to line up, what is the problem?

I'm assuming incorrect calculations

This is just a proof of concept.
So the program just confirms the printed layout content and then sends it to the default printer.
Therefore, the program is also very short and simple. Just enough to complete the proof of concept.
PrintCanvasExample2.java
package com.example.demoticketprintapp;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.print.*;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PrintCanvasExample2 extends Application {
    static String invoice;

    public static String getPrintableText(String[] products) {
        //Label text = new Label();
        //text.setFont(Font.font("Monospaced Regular", FontWeight.LIGHT, 11));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("             Company Name            \n");
        stringBuilder.append("-------------------------------------------" + "\n");
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("%-24s  %5s  %10s\n", "Item", "Qty", "Price"));
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("%-24s  %5s  %10s\n", "----", "-----", "----------"));
        for (String product : products) {
            stringBuilder.append(formatTemplateString(product, 1, 12500));
        }
        stringBuilder.append("___________________________________________" + "\n");
        stringBuilder.append("Net Amount                             5000" + "\n");
        stringBuilder.append("___________________________________________" + "\n");
        stringBuilder.append("Thank you so much!" + "\n");
        //DEBUG
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private void print(Node node) {
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        if (job != null) {
            // Print the node
            boolean printed = job.printPage(node);
            if (printed) {
                // End the printer job
                job.endJob();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Printing failed.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Could not create a printer job.");
        }
    }

    public static String formatTemplateString(String str, long num1, long num2) {
        String formattedStr = String.format("%-24s", str);
        String formattedNum1 = String.format("%5d", num1);
        String formattedNum2 = String.format("%10d", num2);
        String rt = "";
        if (str.length() > 25) {
            if (str.length() <= 44) {
                rt = str + "\n" + " ".repeat(24) + "  " + formattedNum1 + "  " + formattedNum2;
            } else if (str.length() > 44) {
                String str1 = str.substring(0, 44);
                String str2 = str.substring(44);
                rt = str1 + "\n" + String.format("%-24s", str2) + "  " + formattedNum1 + "  " + formattedNum2;
            }
        } else {
            rt = formattedStr + "  " + formattedNum1 + "  " + formattedNum2;
        }
        return rt + "\n";
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400, 300);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

        // setup fonts
        //Linux
        gc.setFont(new Font("Monospaced Regular", 12));
        //WIndows
        //gc.setFont(new Font("Courier New", 12));
        gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        // Draw Text
        //gc.fillText(invoice2, 50, 50);
        gc.fillText(invoice, 50, 50);

        print(canvas);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Print Canvas Example");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] productName = {
                "Android",
                "Mac OS",
                "Windows 10 Operating System",
                "Linux Operating System",
                "Windows Server OS"
        };
        invoice = getPrintableText(productName);
        launch(args);
    }
}

FormatTemlate: 44 char width

if item name length > 24 , keep it in one line
if item name length > 44 , split it into two line

public static String formatTemplateString(String str, long num1, long num2) {
        String formattedStr = String.format("%-24s", str);
        String formattedNum1 = String.format("%5d", num1);
        String formattedNum2 = String.format("%10d", num2);
        String rt = "";
        if (str.length() > 25) {
            if (str.length() <= 44) {
                rt = str + "\n" + " ".repeat(24) + "  " + formattedNum1 + "  " + formattedNum2;
            } else if (str.length() > 44) {
                String str1 = str.substring(0, 44);
                String str2 = str.substring(44);
                rt = str1 + "\n" + String.format("%-24s", str2) + "  " + formattedNum1 + "  " + formattedNum2;
            }
        } else {
            rt = formattedStr + "  " + formattedNum1 + "  " + formattedNum2;
        }
        return rt + "\n";
    }

DEBUG OUTPUT
             Company Name            
-------------------------------------------
Item                        Qty       Price
----                      -----  ----------
Android                       1       12500
Mac OS                        1       12500
Windows 10 Operating System
                              1       12500
Linux Operating System        1       12500
Windows Server OS             1       12500
___________________________________________
Net Amount                             5000
___________________________________________
Thank you so much!


Printer output:


if item name length > 24 && < 44, keep it in one line
if item name length > 44 , split it into two line

Item name = "Windows 10 Operating System Windows 10 Operating System - long name"

JDK + JavaFX - Zulu - 21.0.3.fx-zulu

Brother, I did not understand the idea. You provided hard coded formatted data to the canvas. But the data in the question is just a sample, will be changed in every print. So need to be formated dynamically according to the string length. can you suggest anything else?

(1) This code as a POC is used to verify two things, 1. The typesetting of alphanumeric spaces can be aligned using a specific font (Monospaced Regular or others). 2. You think the example provided before (github) is an AWT example and not a JavaFX example. (2) If you StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();  stringBuilder.append(" Company Name \n");  stringBuilder.append("------------------------------------------------ " + "\n"); can finally be combined into the Text format of My test data, and can be applied to my above program paragraph gc.fillText(" Company Name\n" ....

@Qaisar Shabbir  I update my code add formatTemplateString

Thanks Bro, You helped me lot. Just tweaked your solution little bit. No need this condition if (str.length() <= 44) {. Also substring(0, 24) provide smooth result. Both updates are in the formatTemplateString() function.

@Qaisar Shabbir   (1) No need this condition if (str.length() <= 44)  , (2) My Codition is if item name length > 44 , split it into two line and if item name length > 24 , keep it in one line ,  (3) One of the problems with this POC program is that I don’t know the length specification of Item. What is the longest length? So I assume (a) it will exceed 24 and not exceed the boundary (44), (b) it is also possible that it will exceed the boundary (44) ), (c) Even it will exceed 88 (two columns) (I did not write the logic in this part)
